# Do I have to use current limiting resistor for LED in this configuration?

Tags: led, current-limiting

[image]

LM741 datasheet says that it can output a maximum of 20-25 mA. So in this case, is that R5 a must, or will it be safe not using it?

Assuming LEDs can withstand 25mA.

Comment: you're not reading the datasheet correctly, again. the 20 mA output current aren't specified for single-ended 9V supply, but for +-15V; also, this is an opamp, and not in a constant current configuration, but in some comparator (?) configuration (please, don't post yet another question trying to use the worst opamp in the world as a comparator), so this really isn't what you want, at all.

Comment: Also, that is a **typical** figure in the datasheet. That means "in this order of magnitude"; nothing more, nothing less.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I am not trying to build something very-well designed, able to operate very precisely. I will need it only for 10 minutes or so. And after many times I have pointed out, I actually **must** use an opAmp, and cannot use a comparator(not allowed). If i could, after all answers to my other questions, I would. I understand that you want to make aware of using LM741 is a way worse solution than using a comparator, and I appreciate this. However, if the above circuit does the job and make the LEDs shine when V+>V- and cuts the current for reverse, it is the only thing I expect from it.

Comment: "I'm not trying to design something well-designed" means that you're buildings something badly designed; your choice, but "please verify my bad design" really helps nobody.

Comment: Op Amps use a good design (Q15,Q14 +Re) to limit current to 25mA but the emitter Re value of 25 Ohms has a 40% tolerance  so 25 mA is nom. 10 min  35 max that's why It's a poor method , but if you design for 15mA 40% tolerance is OK

Comment: You can "get away with" no resistor but it's VERY poor practice and the current is not "designed". Using a resistor and working within the recommended op amp conditions gives much more consistent results. || The LM741 is a VERY VERY old OpAmp that is hard to use (dual supply & more). Use an LM324 (quad) or LM358 (dual) - cost less, single supply, about the same performance, very available.

Comment: @RussellMcMahon actually, already, my thinking was using LM324( for being single supply) and also 220 ohms resistor. This question was more intended to be focused on "is there any chance the LEDs get destroyed while output current is restricted certainly". I have used LM741 in question because I knew its max out current was in the safe range of LED operation.(LM324 was 35-40 mA, so I thought asking the question with LM324 may make the question meaningless).

Comment: @muyustan The LM314 Iout max will varty somewhat with maker but eg [tHIS ti VERSION](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm124-n.pdf) page 5 says 20 mA typical and 40 mA MAX **but* that is at Vcc = 15v AND Vout = 2v!!!! (clamped low by load).  You can expect Iout typical of say 10 mA in your situation. || Your 2 x LEDs will drop ABOUT 4V. So 9-4 = 5V for resistor so I~~~= V/R = 5/150 =~ 33 mA IF the opamp will supply it (unlikely).  If your LED died at 25 mA then an outlier opamp MIGHT kill it WITH the resistor (but, almost certainly not.) .

Comment: @RussellMcMahon "outlier opamp" ?

Comment: @muyustanoutlier -> something at the extreme of a distribution - in this case an especially good one. It's unlikely that any would be "good enough" - and LEDS rated at say 20 mA max will **usually** degrade faster but not fail fatally at say double rated current.

Answer (score 3):

This depends on if it's for production (making thousands) or a hobby one off project.
The 741 will current limit and the voltage will drop.  The opamp will probably get toasty and not operate near it's ideal specs.

Better would be to design a current source, and not to stress out your components.  Here is one of many ways of making a current source.

[image]

Comment: by current source, do you mean amplifying the current via an npn so that opAmp does not have to supply much current continiously? And yes, it is similir to a hobby project.

Comment: @muyustan Yes, the NPN transistor carries the bulk (nearly all) of the current and the opamp controls how much current is going to flow through the NPN.

Comment: Hmm, I am trying to understand your example circuit, but cannot say I am totally into it. How should I implement your design into my configuration? A little bit explanatory answer would be nice. I mean I could not understand how the activate/deactive output current flow mechanism works here.

Comment: There are several ways off the top of my head.  The two LEDs are the *Load*. To turn them off/on you can put a FET in series with them to open their current path.